# Issue with just_audio_background Plugin Triggering Notification Sound on Play/Pause in Some Android Devices

Tags: android, flutter, android-notifications, just-audio

## **Description:**

I'm encountering an issue with the current behavior of the plugin on certain Android devices. Specifically, when a play/pause action occurs within the app, it triggers a notification sound.

## **Problem:**

The issue arises particularly on some Android devices where the plugin generates a notification sound with every play/pause event. While it's possible to disable notification sounds by disabling sound for all notification, doing so affects other important notifications within the app, which is not desirable.

## **Comparison with Spotify:**

I've observed that Spotify, doesn't exhibit this behavior on the same affected devices. Even with notification sounds enabled for Spotify, it doesn't trigger any sounds when the play/pause state changes.

I tried with disabling notification sound but it did stopped sound for all notifications.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem was caused because there are some device which do not have silent notification feature due to which whenever the state of audio player notification changes it triggers notification sound.